# Reset cell value to 001 on start of each month-VBA

Tags: vba, excel

```
Sub incr() 
Set C = Range("Y6")    
For Each cc In C
cc.Value = cc.Value + 1
Next
End sub
```

Someone please modify this code, that it would reset to 001 (on start of every month) and then start counting from there.

I think it's possible in formula, since this code overwrites Y6 formula will be of no use.

Comment: **Please read : http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask**  Further more, your explanation isn't clear at all and your code does nothing else that to add 1 to the value in the cell, so we can't understand anything from it! Please **edit** (click on "edit" at the bottom of your post) your post to improve it

Answer (score 1):

The premise of this request is rather simple, you just need an `If` block to test for the day number - **however** - you need to think about this carefully, because if you rely on a date, then the code will reset the value *every time* it's run on that date.

```
If Day(Date) = 1 Then
    cc.Value = 1 '// This will happen every time the code is run on day 1
Else
    cc.Value = cc.Value + 1
End If
```